# Sharepoint 365 Document Library Calculated Column Searching for Text

Tags: document-library, calculated-column, document

I am trying to search in the files names for HC, so I can have a Yes / No output to be able to filter on it, since MS does not have a does not contain option in filter.

Names of the File:

SLS802 2021 Price Increase Stick Report by Cust Location - Prod Family - HC - Canada_03162021.xlsx 
SLS802 2021 Price Increase Stick Report by Cust Location - Prod Family - HC - Canada_03162021.pdf

When I try to use the formula:
=ISNUMBER(FIND("HC",Name)) it gives me error messages of the column does not exist.

If I use the formula:
=ISNUMBER(FIND("HC",[Title]))

it gives me the output of No

I have also tried:

=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("HC",[Title])), "OK", "Not OK")

it gives me the output of Not OK, so its saying that everything is false

I am not sure how to have it search and be true

Picture of the document library below

[image]

Also picture of the document library:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you create a calculated column formula, [Name] column doesn't show up as an option in the "Insert Column" list. So, it's not supported to be used in Calculated column formulas.

You could use [Title] column. However, your [Title] column is empty as you haven't populated it with any data. I'm afraid your option here is to use Workflows or Power Automate to accomplish this task.

More info on FIND and SEARCH functions: [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-function-06213f91-b5be-4544-8b0b-2fd5a775436f) and [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/search-function-dax)